# How to determine URL about to be opened by the NewWindow event?

Tags: vb.net, url, event-handling, popup, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to build a simple desktop application to keep users on a certain website.  It's very simple, just a webbrowser control with right click disabled.  However certain applications on our website require popup windows and those windows always open up a full browser window.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.NewWindow        
    'What will the URL of this new window be?
    Console.WriteLine("New Window maybe to " & WebBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri)

End Sub
```

Catching the newwindow event seems straight forward, but the event does not specify the URL that is being passed to the new window.  I have seen some mention of a "NewWindow2" event, but vb.net does not appear to have anything like that.

How can I get the URL that is about to be opened in a new window?

The link is generated from a normal web application and not through a webbrowser.navigate call so it could be just about anything.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the NewWindow2 event, create a new browser instance, host it in a new form or tab and pass it to ppDisp, then handle BeforeNavigate2 to get the new url. You can cancel the navigation if necessary. See [Handle the BeforeNavigate2 event in the new window to get the url.](http://jiangshengvc.wordpress.com/2009/11/22/how-to-force-popup-window-to-navigate-in-the-same-window-in-a-webbrowser-control/) for details.